# How to solve for unknown variables in r?

Tags: r, statistics

How do I set two equations equal to each other in R to solve?

For example:

```
xlog(x)=8273
```

Find X?

Comment: I'm surprised an internet search found nothing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use equation in the form: `x*log(x)-8273 = 0`

You should have some idea of the range in which the answer lies. Then use uniroot function:

```
f <- function(x)  (x*log(x)-8273)
uniroot(f, lower=0.1, upper=100000000)$root
[1] 1170.897
```

Or a more general form:

```
f <- function(x,y)  (x*log(x)-y)
uniroot(f, y=8273, lower=0.1, upper=100000000)$root
[1] 1170.897
```

Answer (score 5):

It turns out (with a little help from Wolfram Alpha) that this *particular* solution is related to the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W) (which Wolfram Alpha calls the "product log" function):

```
library(emdbook)
exp(lambertW(8273))  ## 1170.897
```

The Lambert W is available in several other R packages (LambertW, spatstat, pracma, condmixt, VGAM) as well.