# Solving for a Parameter within a Function in R

Tags: r

If I have a function

```
 fun=function(x,y) {x^2+y^2}
```

where x and y are vectors. I would like to to find the "x" such that x^2+y^2=z, numerically in R. How do I so? I tried using the `solve` command but I am not sure how to specify...keep vector y the same values, solve/minimize the distance/error from the function x^2+y^2 to z to 0.

Comment: What are y and z values? Give some example vectors.

Comment: `solve` is specifically for linear systems and probably won't help here.

Comment: y and z are uniformally distributed random variable from 1 to a 100. If solve is only for linear variables, what command should I used to find the "x' that equates the two sides

Comment: If `y` and `z` are uniformly distributed from 0 to 100, then when y>10 then the root is complex. Is there anything keeping `y` from being less than `sqrt(z)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution involving `uniroot`:

```
fun <- function(x,y) x^2 + y^2

solfun <- function(z,y) {
  if (y^2 > z) return(NaN)
  return(uniroot(function(x) z - fun(x,y), c(0,1e10))$root)
}

z <- sample(1:100,5,repl=TRUE)
y <- sample(1:100,5,repl=TRUE)

unlist(Map(solfun,z,y))
```

As with any root finding algorithm, it can only get approximate answers:

```
> solfun(20,3)
[1] 3.31661
> solfun(10,3)
[1] 0.9999985
```

While the above function works on individual pairs of `z` and `y` values, by using `Map` we can apply the function to vectors.

```
set.seed(4)
z <- sample(1:100,5,repl=TRUE)
y <- sample(1:100,5,repl=TRUE)

> unlist(Map(solfun,z,y))
[1]      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN 4.242638
```

Note that the overwhelming majority of z,y pairs have complex roots.

Comment: y and z need to be vectors according to the question.

Comment: Uniroot is generally useful for complex equations which cannot be simplified to for x = ... For simpler equations one does not need uniroot. Also uniroot needs a range in which the answer lies to be given. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101091/how-to-solve-for-unknown-variables-in-r/25101249#25101249

Comment: I see. In this case, we know the range. 0<=x<=10.

Answer (score 1):

Following may be helpful:

```
z = sample(1:100, 100, replace=T)
y = sample(1:100, 100, replace=T)

x =  mapply(function(z,y) sqrt(z-y^2), z,y)
dd =data.frame(z=z,y=y,x=x)
dd[!is.na(dd$x),]
     z y        x
51  27 2 4.795832
54  78 5 7.280110
66  74 5 7.000000
70  33 1 5.656854
83  81 9 0.000000
100 29 1 5.291503
```