# How to find the value of x based on the results of the function in R

Tags: r

Imagine that I  have a vectors called a_vector:

```
a_vector<-seq(1:10)
```

And I wrote a function to estimate some parameters. Say the function is the following, which I used to estimate the values in the b_vector (note that the actual function that I am using  is more complicated and I cannot discuss it without some extensive lines of code).

```
my_function<-function(a){
  a*sqrt(5)
}

b_vector<-my_function(a_vector)

b_vector
```

and this is the results:

2.236068  4.472136  6.708204  8.944272 11.180340 13.416408 15.652476 17.888544 20.124612 22.360680

Now, imagine that I have values in the b_vector (e.g., 14.99, or 112.85) that I did not estimate by using the function. But, I am interested to know, which values in the a_vector could result those values, even though a_vector currently does not currently contain those values.

I could easily find the values of a_vector based on the values of the b_vector that resulted from the function (e.g., 4.472136 is the result of entering 2 into the function) but I could not find a solution to my problem. I very much appreciate any help with this.

I did not try anything specific because I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: here you could create the inverse function: `b_vector / sqrt(5)` returns `1:10`. Do you the function beforehand?

Comment: So, the actual function is more complicated than this, and I am not sure if I can do a simple reverse function like that. So,  I am looking for a general way of recovering the value of a_vector based on any value in the b_vector.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081479/solving-for-the-inverse-of-a-function-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438362/solving-for-a-parameter-within-a-function-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse a numerical function in R, as long as it is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) by using `optim`, for example if we define this function:

```r
reverse_fun <- function(fun, output) {
  unlist(lapply(output, function(x) {
    suppressWarnings(optim(x, \(y) abs(x - fun(y)))$par)
  }))
}
```

Then we should be able to give it the function we want to reverse and the vector of outputs for which we want to find the inputs. It will return the input that gives the output from a given function:

```r
b_vector <- c(2.236068, 4.472136, 6.708204, 8.944272, 11.180340, 
              13.416408, 15.652476, 17.888544, 20.124612, 22.360680)

my_function <- function(a) {
  a * sqrt(5)
}

reverse_fun(my_function, b_vector)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Your example function *is* bijective, since its domain and codomain are mapped with a one-to-one relationship, which is why this works. This may not be the case with your *actual* function. For example, if your function was `f <- function(x) x^2` and the output vector was `c(4, 9, 16)`, there is no way to tell if the original input was `c(2, 3, 4)` or `c(-2, -3, -4)`, or some mixture of the two. Similarly, trigonometric functions like `sin`, `cos` and `tan` are not bijective.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, I'm necessarily several version of R behind by now.  What is this `\(y)` syntax. I've not seen this.

Comment: @Benjamin it is shorthand for `function(y)`, mostly used for lambda-type functions in lapply, Map, etc. Has been part of base R since (I think) v4.0.0

Comment: Ah.  Thank you. Looks like it came around in 4.1.0. Sadly, I am relegated to 4.0.3 for the time being :(  Guess I need to get back to reading the updates.

Comment: Thanks Guys. Your comments are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for is `uniroot`.

`uniroot` will search for a solution to the first argument of a function where the function returns 0 when given all other arguments. In your case, you are dealing with

`b = sqrt(5) * a`

This implies `0 = b - sqrt(5) * a`.

Now you may do

```
solve_fn <- function(a, b){
  b - a * sqrt(5)
}

uniroot(f = solve_fn, 
        interval = c(-1e8, 1e8), # search interval, a numeric range.
        b = 10)

$root
[1] 4.472136

$f.root
[1] -1.354202e-08

$iter
[1] 2

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

This tells us that `a = 4.472136` is the value that returns `b = 10`.

Ideally, limiting your search interval can be more efficient, but I often set my interval wide if I'm not really sure what the expected search interval might be. Especially if I'm generalizing a function.